# How to add a segmented control to a navigation bar ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, navigationbar

I would like to add a segmented control to a navigation bar like this 
[image]

but when i drag the segmented control to the navigation bar the large title is gone. How can create the above UI ?

Answer (score 12):

You should add the segmented control as the `titleView` of the navigation bar.
Below is the sample code:

```
let titles = ["All", "Missed"]
segmentControl = UISegmentedControl(items: titles)
segmentControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
segmentControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
for index in 0...titles.count-1 {
    segmentControl.setWidth(120, forSegmentAt: index)
}
segmentControl.sizeToFit()
segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentChanged), for: .valueChanged)
segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
segmentControl.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
navigationItem.titleView = segmentControl
```

Comment: It works for me, thank you. Do you know a solution that doesn't requires to add the SegmentedControl programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below simple code,

```
var segmentedController: UISegmentedControl!

let items = ["Label A", "Label B"]
segmentedController = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
navigationItem.titleView = segmentedController
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSignOut))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add UISegmentControl by using XIB then you can do that by following these simple steps:

1. Design your custom view in XIB (Refer XIB for your reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJDCo.png)
2. Put the code in your ViewController

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       lazy var navSegmentedView: YourCustomView = {
           guard let aView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("\(YourCustomView.self)", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? YourCustomView else { return YourCustomView() }

           aView.backgroundColor = .clear
           aView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 40)
           aView.segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

           return aView
       }()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           setupNavBar()
       }

       func setupNavBar() {
           navigationItem.titleView = navSegmentedView
           navigationItem.titleView?.backgroundColor = .clear
       }

       @objc func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
           print(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
       }

    }
   ```